# What's the problem here? and how to fix it

Tags: c

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 65;

char c = (char)a;
    int m = 3.0/2;

    printf("%c\n", c);              // output: A
    //printf("this %f\n", 5 / 2); //0.000000
    printf("%f\n", (float)a);       // output: 65.000000
    printf("this %f\n", 5 / 2);   //65.0000
    printf("%f\n", 5.0 / 2);        // output: 2.5000000
    //printf("this %f\n", 5 / 2);      2.500
    printf("%f\n", 5 / 2.0);        // output: 2.5000000
    //printf("this %f\n", 5 / 2); 2.5000
    printf("%f\n", (float)5 / 2);   // output: 2.5000000
    //printf("this %f\n", 5 / 2); 2.500
    printf("%f\n", 5 / (float)2);   // output: 2.5000000
    //printf("this %f\n", 5 / 2); 2.5000
    printf("%f\n", (float)(5 / 2)); // output: 2.0000000 - we cast only after division and result was 2
    //printf("this %f\n", 5 / 2); 2.0000000
    printf("%f\n", 5.0 / 2);        // output: 2.5000000
    //printf("this %f\n", 5 / 2); 2.500
    printf("%d\n", m);              // output: 1
    //printf("this %f\n", 5 / 2); 2.500

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Why is everything that is written in each comment changed, and why does this change happen in every comment? 
For example in the first comment it's 0.00 why this happens and how to fix it

Comment: What is the expected output and what is the actual output? This is a mess.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you invoke undefined behavior by using the wrong format specifier. `5/2` will evaluate to `2` with type `int`, but you use `%f` to print it. You should either change `5/2` to `5.0/2` so it is of type `double` or print it with `%d`.

```
printf("this %f\n", 5.0/ 2);
```

or

```
printf("this %d\n", 5 / 2);
```

Comment: Ok, but why does not it register 2 and not 2.5 because it from int is not supposed to refer to the point.
Why is he writes 0.00 or 65.000 and not 2

Comment: @bla Because you tell `printf` that you will pass a `double` but pass an `int`. What happens after is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). There is no need to try to understand what happens, it is just undefined. It `Renders the entire program meaningless if certain rules of the language are violated.`

Comment: But I wonder why it happens.
And why when I made an int into char in the first row it introduced 0,
And why do I do float in the row after which it introduced 65?
Does this always show the next line?

Comment: It is really just undefined but this is what `maybe` happens: Since you tell `printf` that you pass a `double` it fetches 8 bytes (`sizeof double`) of the stack, since you only pass 4 bytes (`sizeof int`) the other 4 are not initialized and maybe loaded from a previous function call. But as I said there is really no need to try to understand (and you mostly can not understand) whats happening. Undefined behavior is just undefined.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Osiris' answer a bit...

`printf` is what is known as a *variadic* function - it takes a variable number of arguments.  The function prototype looks like this:

```
int printf( const char * restrict format, ... );
```

This means that the function takes one fixed parameter (`format`) and then some unknown number (zero or more) additional parameters.  Now, here's the problem - the only way `printf` knows that there are additional arguments and what their types are is by what you specify in the `format` string.  `printf` doesn't know - it *can't* know - what you actually pass in the argument list.  It only knows what you *claim* will be in the argument list based on the conversion specifiers you use in the format string.

If you write

```
 printf( "%f\n", 1.0, 2, "3", '4', 5.0 );
```

then as far as `printf` is concerned, you only passed the single additional `double` argument `1.0`.  Even though you passed 5 arguments after the format string, `printf` looks at that single `%f` and concludes there's only a single additional argument.  Note that this particular situation is well-defined - the additional arguments are evaluated, but otherwise ignored.  This is "safe" in the sense that the behavior of your code here is predictable.

If you write

```
printf( "%f\n" );
```

then you have a problem, because `printf` assumes there's an additional `double` argument, *and it will go looking for it* (either in a register or on the stack, depending on the calling convention).  In this case, the behavior is *undefined* - the end result can be anything, from garbage output to an outright crash.

If you write

```
printf( "%f\n", 5 / 2 ); // int / int == int
```

you have one of two problems.  If function arguments are passed by registers, then you have the same problem as above (integer arguments are typically passed in a different set of registers than floating point arguments, so `printf` will look in the wrong register).  If function arguments are passed via stack, then `printf` will grab the next `sizeof (double)` bytes off of the stack and interpret them as a `double`.  In this case, the problem is that the representation of `int` and `double` can be *radically* different.  In a 32-bit `int`, `2` is typically represented as `0x00000002`.  In a 64-bit `double` (assuming IEEE-754 representation), `2.0` is represented as `0x4000000000000000`.  Again, this behavior is *undefined* - you can't trust any result you get.